# Restricted validators names in Angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-validation

I've created custom validator and attached it to the input element's model like:

```
ngModel.$validators.required = function (value) {
  return !!value;
}
```

And it does not work - function is not even called. However renaming it from `required` to `alsoRequired` - it is called properly.

Does Angular have some restrictions about validators naming ?

Comment: required is a default validator available in angularjs.

Comment: you could directly use `ng-required="expression"` to set required attribute dynamically'

Comment: @sms So I cannot overwrite it ? Even set another one with the same name when the native isn't used ?

Comment: @hsz, you can overwrite - but depends on where you overwrite (pre- or post-link) and the relative priority of another directive that sets it.

Comment: @hsz, did any of the below address your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't enough code to understand exactly what is going on, but I could guess where your mistake is:

`ngModel.$validators` is set by any directive that decides to set it. For example, an input directive with `type="email"` sets `$validators.email`; `ng-required` directive sets `$validators.required`, and so on.

You may have `ng-model` set on a custom directive or even on `<input type="text">`, which on its own doesn't register a validator.

Custom directives, like yours, can register a validator:

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel){
  ngModel.$validators.required = function (value) {
    console.log(value); // this will fire if parsers do not return undefined
    return !!value;
  };
})
```

And if set in combination with `ng-model`, should work fine:

```
<input type="email" ng-model="foo" my-dir>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/1oQGRWZ0kWlV6Q7WjvrY?p=preview

To answer your question, the likely reason why your `$validators.required` function is not called is because you have another directive that overwrites this value - for example, `ng-required`.

Answer (score 0):

You could set required field dynamically for that you can take use `ng-required="expression"` instead of using validator. which will add `required` attribute conditionally if `expression` would be `true`

Comment: Thanks, but that's not the case. I'm just asking, why it does not set my validator or overwrite the Angular's one.